# Intellij keys registration

Tags: intellij-idea

As a life long eclipse IDE user, i decided to try Intellij at work. I requested for activation keys and received them. Thing is, the registration process to upgrade from a trial version to a full version is very confusing. Any pointers over this issue will help.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `Help` | `Register` dialog to enter the key for IDEA Ultimate. If the Help Register is disabled then you might be using EAP(Early Access Program) version of the product.

Note that Help menu is not available from the welcome screen, so you need to create/open some project first.

To access registration dialog from the Welcome Screen use the **Find Action** shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), type `Register...`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: Register]

---

If <kbd>OK</kbd> button remains disabled, refer [to this document](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23354372).

Comment: @CrazyCoder..yep, i followed the Help|Register route. The next page that follows is the problem. I do not know if its my key or what-else...i check the "Enter-license data" but when i insert my given key, the ok button remains inactive. I am of the opinion that if you insert your keys, the ok button should be active. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: @KennethChidozieObikwelu Are you also entering the name under which you registered IntelliJ?

Comment: @CrazyCoder...The keys were issued from work. So i assume that all i need to do is use my name and insert the given keys.

Comment: @KennethChidozieObikwelu You have to use whatever name was given when getting the registration key. Anything else will not work. You'll have to ask whoever at your work got the keys for the name they used. If the name they used is the name you're trying to put into the registration dialog, then you probably need to contact JetBrains for help.

Comment: See [this document](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23354372).